# What is the unit used when using the SetBalance() function of the state package?

Tags: solidity, go-ethereum, ether

Maybe I missed it, but can't seem to find it anywhere. Is the unit used in Gwei or in Eth?

For example when writing :

```
stateDb, err := state.New(rootHash, db)
if err!=nil{
   return err
}
addressA := common.HexToAddress("0xAb5801a7D398351b8bE11C439e05C5B3259aeC9B")

stateDb.SetBalance(addressA, big.NewInt(1000))
```

do we get 1000 eth or 1000 wei?

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`state_object.go`](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/blob/ee92bc537f159c2202058a33e015684cc2bca04c/core/state/state_object.go#L96), the state code deals with the following account representation:

```
// Account is the Ethereum consensus representation of accounts.
// These objects are stored in the main account trie.
type Account struct {
    Nonce    uint64
    Balance  *big.Int
    Root     common.Hash // merkle root of the storage trie
    CodeHash []byte
}
```

`setBalance()` works on this representation of `Balance`.

The state representation in the code is a direct implementation of the specification in the Yellow Paper. The description of world state in section 4.1 of the [Yellow Paper](https://gavwood.com/paper.pdf) has this to say:

> **balance**: A scalar value equal to the number of Wei owned by this
>   address

Comment: No problem, glad it helped :-)

Answer (score 1):

It is impossible to answer without more information or code to see.

However, it is likely in `wei`. All values in Solidity are in `wei`, unless they are suffixed with a keyword such as `ether`, `szabo`, or `finney`.